# Add RealmObject to a List without adding it to the Realm

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-list

I know there are differences between managed `RealmList` and unmanaged `RealmList`. I don't get how I can decide whether my list is managed or not. I create the list as follow: 
`myList = new RealmList();` 
I populate the list as follow: 
`myList.add(item);` 
Every item I add to the RealmList is added to the Realm, and I don't want it because I'm developing a personal library of items and want the Realm to contain only items user needs in his library. Every item has a 'related' list in which I add other items (adding them to the realm too, even if I don't want to). 
Is there a way in which I could just add them to the `RealmList` without adding them to the Realm too?

Comment: Is it possible to you use java `List` instead of `RealmList`?

Comment: @ilya no because the list is inside a RealmObject, which accepts only RealmList

Comment: have you tried annotate that list with `@Ignore`? https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#ignoring-properties

Comment: That's not what I want. I want that List to be on the Realm if the Item that has the list is in the Realm. I'm fetching data from an API, the user can add the item to his library (which will add the item to the realm). If the user does not add the item on the Realm, he can still see this related list

Comment: This question is unclear because I do not understand why you want to add items to a list without adding items to the list.

Comment: I want to add items to the Item's list, not in the Realm

Comment: It seems that this question is not about realm it self but about design your data entities and queries. There are a lot of ways to achieve it. You can inherit `Item` to make new kind of entity `UserItem` or/and `UserDraftItem` to distinguish them from each other. It may be tricky to make request which contains all that entities but it is possible and you'll get a clear view of purposes of that entities.

Comment: I did some debug, my List (RealmList<Item>) is always unmanaged, but somehow Item's in list are stored in Realm. That's what I want to avoid. That's all. My data is ok like that

Comment: It is not a bug it is current limitation of Realm https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#limitations
It means that you can not have unmanaged object fields for now.

Comment: So why the `isManaged()` returns false then? Even debugging, no function is called to add Items to the Realm, I can't get why they are added, and how

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following code:

`RealmList<Foo> myList = new RealmList(); 
myList.add(item);`

Nothing is added to Realm. Adding items to Realm can only be done within a write transaction, so doing it outside one is a guarantee it is not persisted by Realm.

Comment: Actually, items are added in list, because when I try to edit them, it says I can't edit Realm items outside a transaction

Comment: So you are adding managed Realm objects to an unmanaged list?

Comment: Maybe that's the problem, how do I create an unmanaged object?

Comment: Just create a normal object using `new <name>()`. Objects are managed if you query them from Realm or use `createObject`

Comment: Then that's not the problem because I create Items with `new Item()`

Comment: Then you need to provide a bigger code sample, because from your description it should work